# Counting Number of Pairs within a String Variable

Tags: r, string

For a research project, I would like to form two groups (e.g. left/right) within a panel data set of a highly fragmented party system, based on a string variable containing the coalitions the parties form, as in column (3) of the following simplified example:

```
parties <- c("A","A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003)
coalitions <- c("A, C, D", "A,C", "A,E", "B,F,G", "B,G", "B,H")
d <- data.frame(parties,year,coalitions)
```

I have two fixpoints, say party A (left) and party B (right). In order to receive two groups, I would like to have a table telling me with which parties these two parties A and B form a coalition with in which quantity, in my example:

Group A: (A,C: 2), (A,D: 1), (A,E: 1)

Group B: (B,G: 2), (B,F: 1), (B,H: 1)

This would allow me to set a threshold (in case there is few parties forming coalitions with both A and B). Could anyone help me out with a solution that *does not* (due to the high number) require the name of other parties than A and B for the coding, ideally based solely on column (3)? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>%
  separate_rows(coalitions) %>%
  filter(parties != coalitions) %>%
  count(parties, coalitions)

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   parties coalitions     n
#   <fct>   <chr>      <int>
# 1 A       C              2
# 2 A       D              1
# 3 A       E              1
# 4 B       F              1
# 5 B       G              2
# 6 B       H              1
```

Comment: The best way to fix it is to update your question including a case like this and specify how the output should look like.

Comment: Thank you, the code works, I just had to do minor changes in my dataset.